# HGPlaceholders Button Actions Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, button

I'm still learning Swift and therefor don't understand how certain things work - like Placeholders. I installed HGPlaceholders into my project for use with TableViews that I have downloading information from Firebase. I can't seem to figure out how to give the various screens' (there's multiple screens and they each have one "Try Again!" or "Cancel" button) button an action though.

Would someone who is familiar with HGPlaceholders please help me out? How do I give something like
`tableView.showLoadingPlaceholder()`
an action? Currently it just prints something out to the console, by default.

Yes, I read the documentation for it. Yes, I searched the internet for help. No, I couldn't find **anything** addressing this question.

Thanks!

HGPlaceholders: [HGPlaceholders Documentation](https://github.com/HamzaGhazouani/HGPlaceholders)

This is what the function that by default prints something when the button in the placeholder is tapped looks like:

```
@IBAction func sendPlaceholderAction(_ sender: Any) {
   onActionButtonTap?()
   print("Placeholder action button tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... took me forever cause I'm stupid.

The actions are handled in this function that you place at the bottom of the class your table view is located in:

```
extension TestViewController: PlaceholderDelegate {
    
    func view(_ view: Any, actionButtonTappedFor placeholder: Placeholder) {
        print(placeholder.key.value)
        if placeholder.key.value == "loading" {
            print("The placeholder is the Loading screen and Cancel button")
        } else if placeholder.key.value == "noResults" {
            print("The placeholder is the noResults screen and Try Again button")
        } else if placeholder.key.value == "noConnection" {
            print("The placeholder is the noConnection screen and Try Again button")
        } else if placeholder.key.value == "error" {
            print("The placeholder is the error screen and Try Again button")
        }
    }

}
```

This is an example of giving an action to each of the four .default options.

Hope this helps anyone else who couldn't figure it out haha!

Side note: One other thing, you have to set your tableView's placeholderDelegate in the viewDidLoad as well.

```
tableView.placeholderDelegate = self
```

If you don't, the function will never execute.